# Django 1.7.1 dumpdata progress bar

Tags: django, dumpdata

I have an existing project in **django 1.7.1**, but from **django 1.9.1** a new feature had been introduced in the `dumpdata` command (--output)

```
python manage.py dumpdata --output backup.json
```

On executing this command we can see the progress bar in the terminal(Progress of the `dumpdata` to a json file). 
Is there any way to achieve this in django 1.7.1, can we do any additional functionalities in our project?, please help me for this.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible solution is to add to your application new command which would be a **port of django 1.9.1 command** - this is [the commit to django repo](https://github.com/django/django/commit/c296e55dc6a697c7e4d4be92b954633cda4a79b1) that introduced the change.

As you can see from the diff the commit modified not only the [dumpdata command](https://github.com/django/django/commit/c296e55dc6a697c7e4d4be92b954633cda4a79b1#diff-ba857293888e3e6a18253d78fb78a598) itself but also [serializers' baseclass](https://github.com/django/django/commit/c296e55dc6a697c7e4d4be92b954633cda4a79b1#diff-7a82040e56038c35d815475a068d481d), so you would have to:

- create new command (identical to django's one) in your application
- copy whole [serializers
  module tree](https://github.com/django/django/tree/c296e55dc6a697c7e4d4be92b954633cda4a79b1/django/core/serializers) to your application
- update created command to import serializers from your application not django core

Huh... **looks like a lot of forking (*copy-pasting*) work, that might be a pain in the future**. If it's so important for you, I would consider adjusting the project to backward incompatible changes and migrating from django 1.7.1 to 1.9.1.